# Designing an image that is a multiple/tile of another image

Tags: logo, responsive-design, tiles, branding

I am trying to come up with a concept design for a background image that uses a repetition and/or tiling of the original image to achieve an effect that allows the audience to recognize the original image as well as the bigger overall image easily.

This was the actual proposed solution to a graphics design problem where a web page has multiple breakpoints that causes some portion of the entire image to be chopped off, hence the image can't be designed as an overall image (or an image with different dimensions to cater for all the breakpoints). The proposed solution was to create a graphic where the brand or logo will still be clear regardless where the image is chopped off.

An example of what I am talking about would be the Microsoft ADFS sign up page:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950(v=ws.11).aspx

Here we have a prescribed template and recommendations regarding size and resolution of the images. Theoretically it is customizable, but if for example there is some technical (e.g. access to the code or markup) or project constraint (e.g. time and resources) that prevents any customization, then you have to try and design an image that negotiates possible breakpoints.

Are there good design principles and techniques of how to design these types of images, or any examples out there anyone has seen that works really well?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're talking about? It seems pretty ambiguous to me

Comment: @ZachSaucier I provided details of the template page I am referring to, you'll have to test to see where the breakpoints are, maybe using http://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/

Comment: @MichaelLai looks like you linked to a documentation page *about* the template page you are talking about, not an actual example, so there's no way to check any breakpoints (I couldn't find a link to an example or any explicit breakpoints listed on that page)

Comment: Also, where does tiling come in to it? The template you're talking about looks like it uses one image with no repeating so I'm not completely sure what you're asking. What is "the original image as well as the bigger overall image"? Isn't there just one image?

Comment: @Cai I have provided a link to show the specifications, but unless you have implemented the website and the login page there won't be an actual example. But you can see that there is a left hand section where they recommend a 1400x1080 size image. Because we have to show our brand/logo somewhere on the page, and it should stand out, logic says that it should be on the left hand size where the larger area is. However, this get chopped off at certain breakpoints so hence the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should just edit your question to include some of the screenshots showing your examples? I'm not sure for how long the linked documentation will stay online, and without it your question would be incomplete and harder to understand.